# How to tell VC++ optimizer not to merge function bodies?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};

struct B {};

int func1(A *a, B *b, int c, double *d) {
    int tmp = 0;
    tmp = tmp;

    return 1;
}

int func2(A *a, B *b, int c, double *d) {
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (func1 == func2) {
        std::cout << "equal" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "not equal" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled in Release configuration in VS2013 it prints out “equal”. I have a library that depends on comparison of function addresses. You can imagine that it doesn't work quite alright in Release. Is there a way to prevent this kind of optimization in VC++? Or should I file a bug?

Comment: What are your command line options? [18.0.21005.1](http://rextester.com/live/NAAYI29768) prints `not equal` here.

Comment: [expr.eq]/2 "Two pointers compare equal if they are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address, otherwise they compare unequal." This is a bug.

Comment: @remyabel try passing `/O2`.

Comment: This is comdat folding in msvc land, and mscv aggressively uses it beyond what C++ allows.

Comment: This is not a bug at all: the pointers compare equal because both represent the same address. I'm not aware of anything in the C++ spec stating that different functions should have different addresses. This is likely an improper assumption of the library's authors.

Comment: “I'm not aware of anything in the C++ spec stating that different functions should have different addresses.”

You serious? dyp posted the spec reference. What else do you need?

It's the very first paragraph of section 5.10 of the standard.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a ["feature"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx) of Microsoft's linker, and the documentation warns you that

> Because /OPT:ICF can cause the same address to be assigned to
>   different functions or read-only data members (const variables
>   compiled by using /Gy), it can break a program that depends on unique
>   addresses for functions or read-only data members.

You can turn it off by passing `/opt:noicf` to the linker.

Comment: @noxmetus note the cost:  massive binary bloat.

Comment: Define “massive”. In my case (in the real application, not in the example I posted) the “bloat” constituted 0.4%.

Comment: Related reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/22/400373.aspx